# Conservation of mass in Integrated surface water and groundwater models

Tags: hydrology, numerical-modelling

One of the fundamental principles in fluid mechanics is the conservation of mass - how is this treated in integrated surface water | groundwater models such as MIKE models, say between two river cross-sections?